# pointcloud_to_laserscan using kinect

Tags: kinect, laserscan, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am using indigo version and I have been trying to convert the depth image to laser scan following this tutorial http://www.hessmer.org/blog/2011/04/10/2d-slam-with-ros-and-kinect/

but I got the following error after executing "roslaunch ./launch/kinect_laser.launch" command

```
[ERROR] [1424961680.546848448]: Failed to load nodelet [/pointcloud_throttle] of type [pointcloud_to_laserscan/CloudThrottle]: According to the loaded plugin descriptions the class pointcloud_to_laserscan/CloudThrottle with base class type nodelet::Nodelet does not exist. Declared types are  depth_image_proc/convert_metric depth_image_proc/disparity depth_image_proc/point_cloud_xyz depth_image_proc/point_cloud_xyzi depth_image_proc/point_cloud_xyzrgb depth_image_proc/register image_proc/crop_decimate image_proc/debayer image_proc/rectify image_rotate/image_rotate image_view/disparity image_view/image nodelet_tutorial_math/Plus openni_camera/driver pointcloud_to_laserscan/pointcloud_to_laserscan_nodelet stereo_image_proc/disparity stereo_image_proc/point_cloud2[FATAL] [1424961680.547091841]: Service call failed!

[ERROR] [1424961680.592416238]: Failed to load nodelet [/kinect_laser] of type [pointcloud_to_laserscan/CloudToScan]: According to the loaded plugin descriptions the class pointcloud_to_laserscan/CloudToScan with base class type nodelet::Nodelet does not exist. Declared types are  depth_image_proc/convert_metric depth_image_proc/disparity depth_image_proc/point_cloud_xyz depth_image_proc/point_cloud_xyzi depth_image_proc/point_cloud_xyzrgb depth_image_proc/register image_proc/crop_decimate image_proc/debayer image_proc/rectify image_rotate/image_rotate image_view/disparity image_view/image nodelet_tutorial_math/Plus openni_camera/driver pointcloud_to_laserscan/pointcloud_to_laserscan_nodelet stereo_image_proc/disparity stereo_image_proc/point_cloud2[FATAL] [1424961680.592651940]: Service call failed![pointcloud_throttle-23] process has died [pid 7479, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/nodelet/nodelet load pointcloud_to_laserscan/CloudThrottle openni_manager cloud_in:=/camera/depth/points cloud_out:=cloud_throttled __name:=pointcloud_throttle __log:=/home/nouf/.ros/log/4528dc14-bdc1-11e4-84e3-b4749fbdedba/pointcloud_throttle-23.log].log file: /home/nouf/.ros/log/4528dc14-bdc1-11e4-84e3-b4749fbdedba/pointcloud_throttle-23*.log[kinect_laser-24] process has died [pid 7505, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/nodelet/nodelet load pointcloud_to_laserscan/CloudToScan openni_manager cloud:=cloud_throttled __name:=kinect_laser __log:=/home/nouf/.ros/log/4528dc14-bdc1-11e4-84e3-b4749fbdedba/kinect_laser-24.log].log file: /home/nouf/.ros/log/4528dc14-bdc1-11e4-84e3-b4749fbdedba/kinect_laser-24*.log
```

I think some files are missing, but I don't know how to fix it

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203857/pointcloud_to_laserscan-using-kinect/) by [nouf](https://answers.ros.org/users/21560/nouf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2015-02-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That tutorial is over three years old, and is for ROS Diamondback.

Check out the sample launch files here: https://github.com/ros-perception/perception_pcl/tree/indigo-devel/pointcloud_to_laserscan/launch

And the parameter documentation here: http://wiki.ros.org/pointcloud_to_laserscan

---

Originally posted by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) with karma: 4518 on 2015-02-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1